# AdWords AdHoc reporting Java library

Tags: google-ads-api

Has anyone obtained an AdWords API AdHoc-reporting-only Java library? That is a minimalistic version of the AdWords API library, that can cope with AdHoc reporting only. The full blown API library is almost 6 MB large and I'm sure that AdHoc is a small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is such a library so you'd need to build your own. I've seen this type of question several times before, but you should consider the benefits of rolling your own code as 6MB isn't really that much anymore, and Google's client libraries are pretty mature and well supported, so you could just end up waiting time with no real benefit.

However, if you really need to avoid the official SDK, then it's easy enough to construct the SOAP calls without it: Just enable SOAP logging in the client library, extract the XML for the report definition, then modify it as either a text string or using an XML tool.

Comment: Hi Ewan. Thank you for your time. I've tried shrinking it with ProGuard but there's just too much reflection in there and you have to keep so many packages that you end up with something almost as large as the original jar. Thanks for the SOAP suggestion, will give it a try.

Comment: Ewan, hi again. Sorry for the delay. 
We have to set the client customer id as a request property when making the http call. The client customer id can be obtained by calling services such as InfoServiceInterface:

    InfoServiceInterface infoService =     adWordsUser.getService(AdWordsService.V201206.INFO_SERVICE);

                                                                           and for this we still need to use the client library, which btw has gone up to 13MB in version 8.1.1. It's starting to become a problem. Any ideas?